LoadError: cannot load such file -- async-websocket Rails 6.0.2.2
I'm setting rails application on ubuntu GCP VM
After bundle install I see this error
Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- async-websocket
/home/user1/project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/project1/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/user1/project1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@project1/gems/rake-13.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@project1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@project1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Here is my gem list
user1@ubuntu:~/project1$ gem list async

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

async (1.32.1)
async-http (0.60.2)
async-io (1.43.2)
async-pool (0.4.0)
async-websocket (0.8.0)

How do I fix this?
I tried installing different versions of async-websocket gem, but it didn't resolve
Environment version
Ruby 2.7.1
Rails 6.0.2.2

Can you please try this :
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install

This doesn't help, even tried changing the version of async-websocket gem. Gem is getting installed but it is failing to load. Same Gemfile configuration is working on AWS instance, but failing on new instance set up in GCP.
